# MVC 3 Menu navigating to /Gap not /Home/Gap

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Please accept my apologies for the possible simplicity of my question but I am new to MVC 3 and attempting to learn through doing. I have created a new View named Gap within an application however cannot figure out how to reference this page from the top menu. It keeps navigating to /Home/Gap which does not work.

```
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Gap", "Gap")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: Correct me if i am mistaken. You have single controller named Home and 3 action methods Index, Gap and About. Right ?

Comment: Hi Emre, I have 3 controllers, Account, Gap and Home. I then have 4 Views, the view which I want to reference is not within the /Home view, it is separate within a Gap folder so the address I wish to reference is portnumber/Gap. Not /Home/Gap as the application is currently trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your receive HTTP 404 error by saying it does not work, you need to create an action that will return your view to user.

```
<ul id="menu">
     <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
     <li>@Html.ActionLink("Gap", "Gap", "Home")</li>
     <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

You need Get Action for each of your views.

```
namespace Management.Controllers
{
     public class HomeController: Controller
     {    
          //
          // GET: /Home/

          public ActionResult Index()
          {
              return View();
          }

          //
          // GET: /Home/About

          public ActionResult About()
          {
              return View();
          }

          //
          // GET: /Home/Gap

          public ActionResult Gap()
          {
              return View("~/Views/_portnumnber_/Gap.cshtml");
          }
    }
}
```

Without action methods you cannot access your views, it is how MVC works.

I would advise reading the tutorials [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc). It is a good place to start.

Comment: Hi emre, thanks for your comment, unfortunately the view folder which has been created is at the address _portnumnber_/Gap, not /Home/Gap. Is there any way to get to that address from the menu?